# Vue.js Apache configuration with 301 https redirection (mode history)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using vuejs with mode history enabled, and on the docs I find this [Histoy mode docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)

but then using Let's Encrypt with certbot I run a command to generate an ssl certificate, but now because of the redirection the following configuration no longer works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName virtuafest.vir.mx
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/virtuafest17/dist
<Directory /var/www/virtuafest17/dist>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =virtuafest.vir.mx
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I solve this without having to create an .htaccess file for the Rewrite conf?

Answer (score 0):

Locate `VirtualHost: *:443` in `etc/apache2/apache2-le-ssl.conf` and add your `mod_rewrite` there.